# Is my solution to this problem on infinite series problem correct?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Question : To check the cvg/div of series whose nth term is given by $cos(1/n)$ .

My attempt is to expand $cos(1/n)$ as $ 1 - (1/n)^2\2 ..$  .after that taking limits and using nth term test i get 1 so it diverges . am i correct . also is there any other alternate way for this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The limit of $\cos(1/n)$ as $n\to\infty$ is not $0$. It follows that our series diverges. Your argument is correct, but uses more machinery than necessary.

**Remark:** The simplest "divergence test" is based on the fact that if $\sum_1^\infty a_n$ exists, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$.

Comment: i took limit of its terms in expansion out there

Comment: Yes, but too much machinery was used. By the continuity of $\cos x$ at $0$, the limit is not $0$. We do not need the Maclaurin expansion.

Comment: yeah right thanks for answer .ur right mclaurin expansion was unneccesary here . but that will work too

Comment: Your question asked whether your argument is correct. I added to the answer, saying that it is.